# How to convert HTML into endless one-page PDF via wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: command-line, pdf, conversion, parameters, wkhtmltopdf

Currently when converting the PDF from given URL, like:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://superuser.com/ superuser.pdf
```

where it consist multiple A4 pages (so sometimes images are cut in the middle of the page).

My question is:

**How do I convert HTML page into PDF format where the height is endless?**

My preference is that you still should have editable/searchable document, not just an static image.

---

What I've tried already:

- I couldn't find any [valid paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6394905/55075) for that (which seems doesn't work anyway),
- I've seen already: [Auto page size based on content size](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1627) at GitHub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wkhtmltopdf 0.9.6 Manual](https://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html) documents this parameter :

```
    --page-height      <unitreal>      Page height (default unit millimeter)
```

Therefore defining an enormously long page can be done via :

```
--page-height 10000cm
--page-height 100m
```

which both define a page of height of 100 meters
(I mention both in case your wkhtmltopdf does not support `m`).

Not using `wkhtmltopdf`, I do not know if there is some upper limit to
page-height, but you can find that empirically.

In addition you can try to add `--disable-smart-width` (width is not an error) and try for the moment the less ambitious `--page-height 100cm`.

In [this man page](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html) there is a comment about `disable-smart-width` that it's only available using patched QT.

There is also another comment:

> On the wkhtmltopdf website you can download a static version of wkhtmltopdf at http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list. This static binary will work on most systems and comes with a build in patched QT.

The project has moved [elsewhere](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html), so you might hunt there for such a version, or ask in the forums.

Comment: Tested: `wkhtmltopdf http://superuser.com/ superuser.pdf --page-height 100m`, but doesn't seems to work as expected as I still see 3 separate pages. Tested with v0.12.2.1.

Comment: Try to add `--disable-smart-width` (width is not an error) and try for the moment the less ambitious `--page-height 100cm`.

Comment: I've already tried, but it's saying: `Unknown long argument --disable-smart-width`.

Comment: This then relates to another version of wkhtmltopdf. My last suggestion is to test the [beta version](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) including seeing if some pertinent invocation parameter was added (and especially disabling anything with "smart"). If no go, ask in [wkhtmltopdf Spport](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/support.html).

Comment: Tested with the latest dev version from the sources (`0.12.3-dev-8f03630`), the option still doesn't work on OSX (saying it's unknown). The only reference for this option is in [`imagearguments.cc`](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/7f74d893635d275f9450bf5f12c454a9c27672bd/src/image/imagearguments.cc). Maybe it works only for the images (not PDF)?

Comment: @kenorb I find that `--page-height` only works after specifying `--page-width` (version 0.12.6)

Comment: if someone reads this old question, there is feature request as old as the question. It is still not supported read https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4299

Answer (score 0):

You should do it as below:

```
$ wkhtmltoimage http://superuser.com/ superuser.png
loaded the Generic plugin 
Loading page (1/2)
Rendering (2/2)                                                    
Warning: Received createRequest signal on a disposed ResourceObject's NetworkAccessManager. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
Done                                                               
$ geo=$(file superuser.png | awk '{print $5"x"$7}' | sed -e 's/,//')
$ convert superuser.png -page $geo superuser.pdf
```

Convert is performed from the ImageMagick package. The disadvantage of using the method above is that the PDF output would have a static image.

Answer (score 0):

Looking again [inside the code](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/src/lib/pdfsettings.cc) it seems you still cannot select an infinite roll.

So you can simply use the [*imagemagick*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) command `mogrify` with the option `-append` on the downloaded file (or even +append if you want to append  them horizontally).

```
wkhtmltopdf http://superuser.com/ superuser.pdf
mogrify -append superuser.pdf
```

from `man mogrify`

> **-append**
>     append an image sequence top to botto (use +append for left to right)

If you want to create a new file you can use from the same suite `convert`.

```
convert -density 200 superuser.pdf -append superuser.vertical.pdf
```

Comment: I've tried, but the output PDF contain static low-quality image. I've also tried adding: `-units PixelsPerInch -density 300` or `-units PixelsPerInch -resample 300`, but the output PDF is still a low-quality image.

Comment: The `convert` command is really sensible to the position of the parameters. You can try `convert  -density 300 supersuser.pdf -append su.vertical.pdf`... or even more hight density values, and parameters. (Let me know)